# d3js timeseries - svg path has huge values

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to create a time series graph by mimicking this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955):
My data consists of one single day, but with minute-wise snapshots of some values like this..

```
{
  "id": "MT_OUT_total",
  "values": [
    {
      "date": 1483530026,
      "val": 10
    },
    {
      "date": 1483530027,
      "val": 1
    },
    {
      "date": 1483529996,
      "val": 14
    },
    {
      "date": 1483529997,
      "val": 22
    },
    {
      "date": 1483529998,
      "val": 22
    },
    {
      "date": 1483529999,
      "val": 6
    },
    {
      "date": 1483530000,
      "val": 0
    },
    {
      "date": 1483530001,
      "val": 11
    },
    {
      "date": 1483530002,
      "val": 5
    },
    {
      "date": 1483530003,
      "val": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run my program, I only get the axes and labels, but not the line graph itself.  So, I checked in the element inspector, which shows very huge value for svg line command, which is out of the bounds of SVG rectangle (as shown in the pic).  You can see in the pic that the path's move command "M" has a huge value for x coordinate i.e. date (example: d="M1483530026000,159.0909090909091L1483530026166.6667,135.22727272727272C1483530026333.3333....)

It looks like, I am making an error while mapping the range and domain correctly, but I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.  The code is below:

```
 38   createChart() {
 39     this.ctx = {};
 40 
 41     var el = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.d3svg_time_series);
 42     var margin = {top:20, right:80, bottom:30, left:50};
 43     this.ctx.width = this.props.width - margin.left - margin.right;
 44     this.ctx.height = this.props.height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 45     var svg = d3.select(el).append('svg')
 46           .attr('width', this.props.width)
 47           .attr('height', this.props.height);
 48 
 49     this.ctx.g = svg.append('g')
 50           .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
 51 
 52     //var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");
 53     this.ctx.x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, this.ctx.width]);
 54     this.ctx.y = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, this.ctx.height]);
 55     this.ctx.z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
 56                            
 57     var ctx = this.ctx;    
 58     this.ctx.line = d3.line()
 59           .curve(d3.curveBasis)
 60           .x(function(d) { 
 61               return d.date; })
 62           .y(function(d) { 
 63               return ctx.y(d.val); });        
 64 
 65   console.log("Created chart.");  
 66   }

 68   draw(ctx) {
 69     // set the input domains for chart
 70     //ctx.x.domain(d3.extent(this.state.data, function(d) {return d.date; }));
 71     var timeSeries = flatten(this.state.data);
 72     ctx.x.domain(d3.extent(timeSeries));
 73     ctx.y.domain([
 74       d3.min(this.state.data, function(item) { return d3.min(item.values, function(v) { return v.val; }); }),
 75       d3.max(this.state.data, function(item) { return d3.max(item.values, function(v) { return v.val; }); })
 76     ]);
 77     ctx.z.domain(this.state.data.map(function(d) { return d.id; }));
 78 
 79     ctx.g.append('g')
 80           .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
 81           .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + ctx.height + ')')
 82           .call(d3.axisBottom(ctx.x));
```

My question is:
-- After having mapped a domain set of values like (1483530026, 1483529996, ...) to a range of (0..width), then shouldn't D3 take care of creating a SVG path within the range of 0..width?

-- I still see D3 generating line command with domain values.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't D3 take care of creating a SVG path within the range of [0,width]?

Yes, it should, if you used such scale in your line generator, which you didn't.

Thus, this:

```
this.ctx.line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { 
        return d.date; 
    })
    .y(function(d) { 
        return ctx.y(d.val); 
    });
```

Should be:

```
this.ctx.line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { 
        return ctx.x(d.date); //using the scale here
    })
    .y(function(d) { 
        return ctx.y(d.val); 
    });
```